# Manual completly uninstall Chrome & Chrome Canary OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am trying to uninstall/delete chrome & chrome canary, but for some reason, when I restart the computer both programs still there.

I am manually deleting this files and folders

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google
~/Library/Caches/com.google.*
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.*
~/Library/Google
```

I am trying to figure out where is the problem and what can I do to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programs themselves are probably in /Applications

The files you are deleting are most of the data files they use